# Significance bars and asterisks for boxplots

Tags: function, boxplot, significance

Does anybody created a loop or function to draw significance bars (with asterisks *, **, ***) for multiple comparison boxplots?

#### I am using a data frame with multiple variables (19) and the following code:

***boxplots:***

boxplot$STATUS is a variables with 4 levels (A,B,C,D)

```
par(mfrow=c(5,4))
for (i in c(1:19)){
  boxplot(log(cito[,i]+1)~cito$STATUS)
}
```

***TukeyHDT post-test***

```
TukeyHSD(aovp(log(cito$CRP+1)~cito$STATUS,center=T))
```

So, I would like to plot in the loop of the boxplot the results of significance differences between groups `(cito$STATUS)` obtained on TukeyHSD.

I appreciate any help. For a while I'll continue looking for options.

#### Bests

Comment: It would help if you specified the language and what you've tried so far (by pasting the code)

Comment: Hi, Will. That's true. I'll be posting soon my code. But I have no Idea to get the bars. Thanks in advance